# Kafka Stream exceptions won't trigger commit on the input record

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream that listens on a topic and outputs on another. For ex:

```
KStream<String, String> messageStream = builder.stream(inputTopic)
KStream<String, String> processedStream = messageStream.process(() -> new CustomProcessor());
processedStream.to(outputTopic)
```

Inside the process method lets say a NPE occurs. I have implemented an uncaught exception handler that will handle this exception and send the record to dead latter queue. Ofc, this stream will close and after it starts again it will start processing the message again ( because it wasn't commited ). How can i avoid this? How can i commit the record when i receive the exception ?

Comment: Why are you letting NPE occur, though?

Comment: NPE it's just an example, it can be w/e exception, how can i commit the record when i receive an exception and not process it anymore next time?

Comment: Use [`LogAndContinue`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#default-deserialization-exception-handler) handler? But that is for deserialization... You still need to try-catch custom processors, and handle runtime exceptions on your own without crashing the JVM. Any "handled/skipped" offsets will be committed automatically.

Comment: Instead of letting it fail, you can just let your processor not send any downstream record, ie, just don't call `forward()` and let the `process()` method return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that happens inside `CustomProcessor` is under your control. You can wrap your logic into a `try/catch` and route the results to different streams, e.g. by outputting a "valid" flag and using `KStream.split` to split the result of your processing into a DLQ and the result.

Comment: can you give a example? :d

Comment: Check the router pattern and the DLQ pattern here: https://sap1ens.com/blog/2019/12/27/kafka-streams-application-patterns/

Comment: Instead of letting it fail, you can just let your processor not send any downstream record, ie, just don't call forward() and let the process() method return.